# Are there ways to let a sufficiently high Acrobatics(Jump) roll exceed ones Max movement?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement

I'm building a L9 Tier 3 mythic character in a Pathfinder game (with a DM who accepts a lot of 3pp, including Drop Dead Games / Spheres of Power & Might, which I'm using heavily).

Between abilities and items, I could easily have a 200+ foot jump...except that jump is limited to my max walking speed.

Do you know of any items / feats / abilities (1st or 3rd party) that allow one to jump further than their speed, in a single Move action? (Spheres of Might has the absurd Dragoon leap, but it's only as a Full Round action.)

Comment: Where is this limit? I guess I've been playing it wrong?

Comment: @Mołot It's in the rules for the Jump skill, but it doesn't actually limit your jump distance, just how far you can go in a single turn: "No jump can allow you to exceed your maximum movement for the round." Is all that is said.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil I think in 3.5 there were rules that effectively let you 'hang midair' to have the jump continue resolving on your next turn. I don't believe PF has explicit guidance about if you can have a jump that takes > 1 round to complete.

Comment: @JeffFry that's how we were playing it in PF.

Comment: @JeffFry Yes, that's what I'm referring to. No explicit guidance is present in the material and so both Molot's and your interpretations are equally consistent with the written rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Jump vertically

Vertical movement [doesn't](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9o76) normally count against your speed. If you jump 2 spaces forward and 10,000 feet up, that's fine, but not 10 spaces forward.  On planes with subjective gravity you can even change what way is forward and just only go up (or down).

Beyond that, there are many ways to go further than you would normally under the default cap (e.g. by increasing speed or certain interpretations of the [*Rod of Balance*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/rod-of-balance/)), but Dragoon leap is the only way to *remove* the cap entirely short of crazy stuff (e.g. Being a [Hekatonkheires](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/titan/titan-hekatonkheires/) or abusing rules to get 3 extra mythic tiers than you should have so you can get early access to [Seven-League Leap](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths-paizo-inc/champion/champion-path-abilities/seven-league-leap-ex/)), and it doesn't work with just a move action.

## or Jump for a *long time*

Perhaps the closest thing to what you are looking for is [Dragonfly Flight](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/dragonfly-flight-combat/).  You can't qualify for it normally before level 10, but [Master of Many Styles](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/master-of-many-styles/) monks can take whatever style feats they want ignoring all prerequisites, so you could take Dragonfly Style at 1st level and Dragonfly Flight at 2nd (or the reverse order, but you kinda need Dragonfly Style to use Dragonfly Flight, so that would be a bad idea, usually, unless you're starting at level 6+).  Dragonfly Flight lets you initiate a *glide*-spell-like nonmagical effect for free after making a high jump when you qualify for Dragonfly Style (i.e. when there's a vertical surface or object that can support your weight near you, e.g. if you are carrying a tower shield).  That lets you effectively also move 60' horizontally as part of your move-action high jump (assuming you hit at least a DC 49 acrobatics check), and then you could high jump again from the air next round (or, if you really wanted, the same round a second time) to continue jumping as high/long as you like at the cost of a move action each round you want to gain height and at a max speed of 120 feet per round (assuming you don't have any faster movement options to mix in).

It's sort-of like exceeding the jump cap via jumping vertically, but it lets you trade that vertical distance into horizontal motion.  It is, however, extremely silly if you think about it too hard, and points out some of the problems with Pathfinder physics (I can jump off this because it weighs more than me!  I can carry it with me because I am strong! I do both at the same time!  I pull myself up by my own pigtail! I am become Baron Münchhausen, destroyer of believability! )

Comment: Good find, although I would argue that a Tower Shield you have *neither* would "support your weight" *nor* be considered "near you' because it is *on* you, mechanically. I could see the second point going either way, but you definitely cannot support your own weight on your own tower shield mid-air. Otherwise, anyone with a tower shield could climb indefinite heights by jumping from their tower shield to their tower shield.

Comment: @Ifusaso *shrug*, if your GM rules that way (which has no textual support-- the object needs to be able to support your weight, it doesn't need to be able to do that while in midair, fair point on needing to move it adjacent, tho) then either carry around an explicitly-always-allowed tree or just take Dragonfly Wings as well and you can definitely do it with any equal-sized creature (like a sentient quarterstaff or tower shield) or mount (like a riding horse).  Also you can't do it normally because normally you can only jump at most twice before you fall (thrice with a *quick runner's shirt*).

Comment: Intelligent items are not creatures (at all, I think, but definitely not) of the size creature that can wield them. A mount could be plausible and an interesting image if you have a way to bring them with you. And I would say the language *is* there, if a little vague.

Comment: @Ifusaso two handed weapons are the [same size](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#weaponSize) as their wielders.  A sentient medium great sword is [treated as](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/intelligent-items/) a medium construct for dragonfly wings even though, as you correctly suppose, they may technically not be creatures.

Comment: Note that that first source I link is 3.5; Pathfinder as generally played inherits the object sizing rules, the same way it inherits some of the other important but infrequent rule stuff it sorta accidentally didn't port over from 3.5.  That Pathfinder itself is silent on the issue does weaken my position there, though.

Comment: I don't think that FAQ link can be generalized to be about all vertical movement. It say it's about flying. Jump, in contrast, says "No jump can allow you to exceed your maximum movement for the round".

Comment: @JeffFry Yes, but you don't use any movement to go up or down.  Movement happens across squares, so, just like you can run 30' up or downhill just as easily as on flat ground, even though the *distance* covered is different, you can jump up any amount of *distance* as long as it doesn't exceed your movement (i.e. as long as you don't cover more than ~6 squares or however much your movement is).  This is because of the same principle as in the FAQ: the game is largely in 2 dimensions rules-wise even when it's also in three.

Comment: Vertical movement is handled not by *spaces*, but by penalizing your movement in other ways.  In the case of jumping, you get a *ton* less distance high-jumping than long jumping most of the time, because the multiplicative penalties for high jumps are huge.  Just like for flying, though, at some point having enough skill lets you actually go *faster* in the skill-limited but not movement limited direction than normal space-based distance.  For fly that's at, like, ~+10 bonus and is infinite improvement but for jump it's at ~+120 bonus and is marginal improvement.